# npm include myPackages.json from packages.json

Tags: node.js, npm

I need to have more then one packages.json file in my node application.
Is there a way to "include" myPackages.json from the standard packages.json and have it all installed in one npm -install command?

Comment: Just copy+paste it over?

Comment: You might need some more details here. A package.json is supposed to define a single module and all it's dependencies. So your *second* package.json should probably just be another module which is required by your main one.

Comment: Why do you need more than one package.json? What is your exact requirement? It can probably be solved differently

Comment: I am developing an application that does automatic generation of another node application and I would like users to be able and add packages without modifying the generated package.json file.- What I had in mind is to "include" another packages file from the generated packages.json in which the users can add packages